# Bind a new ngModel on an existing element

Tags: angularjs-directive

Suppose I have something that looks like this:

```
<input ng-model="object.properties.property_name" options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="object.save('property_name')">
```

I would like that to instead be really short like this:

```
<input name="property_name" autosave="object">
```

But to do that I need to dynamically bind an ngModel to the existing input. I've shortened it up so far to look like this:

```
<input ng-model="object.properties.property_name" name="property_name" autosave="object">
```

And this is the directive that gets me that far:

```
.directive('autosave', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope : {
            autosave : '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.autosave.save(attrs.name);
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

How do I dynamically add `scope.autosave.properties[attrs.name]` to the ngModel and bind it to the input tag?

Comment: I should point out that I cannot replace the input tag, because autosave could just as easily be applied to a textarea or a select list.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to create a model, which was the original question, but I have made it shorter by pulling the property name from the model like this:

```
<input ng-model="object.properties.property_name" autosave="object">
```

and this directive

```
.directive('autosave', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope : {
            autosave : '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('change', function(){
                var property_name = attrs.ngModel.match(/(?=[^.]*$)(\w+)/)[1];
                scope.autosave.save(property_name);
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

It's not ideal, but it's better.